# SharePoint 2013 external lists only work in page edit mode

Tags: sql-server, azure, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, bcs

I have a site page with 3 external lists which display data through BCS connecting to an Azure SQL database as a web part.

They all display their data correctly when the page is in edit mode, but when saved, it just continually loads each web part and doesn't seem to finish.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

[Edit]: Loading the lists on their own when not inserted to a page will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved my own issue.

Setting the web part miscellaneous properties to "Server Render" has all web parts loading their external data as expected.

My own inexperience seems to be the issue here, but I'm sure people familiar with web parts would know this.

This answer may helps others in the same situation.